Verify detached pkcs7/smime signature with python cryptography
I'm looking to replicate the following command in python:
openssl smime -verify -inform der -in sig.rsa -content data.txt -CAfile ca.crt -purpose any

Given that most other python cryptography projects (pyopenssl, m2crypto, etc) are defunct or planned for obsolescence, I would prefer to use the supported cryptography library. Currently the only references I can find to perform a detached signature verification come from this test file, but relies on internal test resources/libraries. Trying to reverse engineer the source seems beyond my abilities at the moment.
The pkcs7 source code has a sign() function but no verify(). However, this pull request and this issue but suggest this feature is supported.... so how is it done?

Not sure if it is still relevant but you can load your pkcs#7 as a list of x509 certs:
from cryptography import x509
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.serialization import pkcs7

pkcs_certs: List[x509.Certificate] = pkcs7.load_der_pkcs7_certificates(<signature_decoded>)

A possible verification part:
pkcs_certs[0].public_key().verify(
                <attr_signature>, <signed_data>, ECDSA(hashes.SHA256())
            )

not sure that in you case it is enough for the verification process (i'm not verry familiar with openssl processing)
